# Error when POSTing from python requests library; does not occur through alfresco share UI

Tags: python, curl, alfresco

Using OOTB Alfresco 5 Community edition running on Ubuntu14.04

Steps:
Create site through the share UI. 
Copy request as curl from Chromium developer tools.
Reconstructed request in python requests library as:

```
s=requests.post('http://<IP>:8080/share/service/modules/create-site',data=site_data,cookies=THE_cookie
```

Where THE_cookie was obtained via a POST to http://:8080/share/page/dologin, which gave a 200, and site_data has different names to the site created through the share UI.

That request gave a 500 error stating that

```
 u'freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:\n==> success  [in template "org/alfresco/modules/create-site.post.json.ftl" at line 2, column 17]\n\nTip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)??\n\nThe failing instruction:\n==> ${success?string}  [in template "org/alfresco/modules/create-site.post.json.ftl" at line 2, column 15]', ...
```

When in Chromium, there is no response, but a site is created successfully.

I've also not got the curl request from the command line to work -- it needs the CSRF token removed, then gives a 200 and does nothing; no logs. My understanding is that Alfresco always gives a 200 on a successful request regardless of whether it's a GET or POST.

If anyone has any ideas that would be amazing. There doesn't seem to be anything that we can do to get create-site to work outside of the share UI, but we absolutely need it to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script is expecting JSON, you need to set the HTTP header `"Content-Type: application/json"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to Requests [session objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), which are designed to persist session cookies between requests (like a browser do). You can try an approach similar to this:

```
s = requests.session()
s.post('http://<IP>:8080/share/page/dologin', data=login_data)
r = s.post('http://<IP>:8080/share/service/modules/create-site', data=site_data)
```